# Do circuits allow to derive EXPSPACE hardness results?

Tags: complexity-classes, nexp

It seems that encoding an NP-complete problem succinctly often makes it [nexptime-complete](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/3303/4780). For instance, 3SAT or HAMILTONIAN PATH become NEXPTIME-complete when the encoding is succint, eg using circuits.

Can a similar approach be taken for PSPACE-complete problems? For instance, do we get EXPSPACE-completeness if QBF or GENERALIZED GEOGRAPHY are encoded using circuits?

I see Ryan Williams has a [paper](http://www.stanford.edu/~rrwill/qbf-lower-bd.pdf) discussing SUCCINT-QBF but I am not familiar enough with complexity theory to understand it.